# Find all positive integers x , satisfying the inequality for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^+ $

Tags: inequality

Find all positive integers x such that for any $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^+ $ satisfying the inequality $$ x(ab+bc+ca) > 5(a^2+b^2+c^2) $$ and there must exist a triangle with a,b,c as its sides respectively.

---

I really don't know how to approach this question.Please help me.

Comment: Show us your trying.

Comment: This follows immediately from [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125709/show-that-a2-b2-c2-geq-ab-bc-ca-for-all-positive-integers-a-b).

Answer (score 1):

Since $a$, $b$, and $c$ must form sides of a triangle, there exist $p,q,r>0$ such that $a=q+r$, $b=r+p$, and $c=p+q$.  Hence, the required inequality is equivalent to
$$x\,\big((p^2+q^2+r^2)+3(qr+rp+pq)\big)>10\,\big((p^2+q^2+r^2)+(qr+rp+pq)\big)$$
for all $p,q,r>0$.

By taking $p:=1$ and $q,r\to0^+$ in the inequality above, we need $x\geq 10$.  On the other hand, if $x\geq 10$, then
$$\begin{align}x\,\big((p^2+q^2+r^2)+3(qr+rp+pq)\big)&\geq 10\,\big((p^2+q^2+r^2)+3(qr+rp+pq)\big)
\\
&> 10\,\big((p^2+q^2+r^2)+(qr+rp+pq)\big)\,.\end{align}$$
Thus, the set of all viable values of $x$ is $[10,\infty)$.  If you demand that $x$ be an integer, then $x=10,11,12,\ldots$ are good values of $x$.  The inequality is sharp if and only if $x=10$.

Comment: Dear @Batominovski $n=6$ is valid. Try $a=b=c.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Note that $x=6$ is certainly not valid for $(a,b,c)=(10,10,1)$.

Comment: We need existing only. See please better the problem.

Comment: What do you mean? The problem statement says that for **any** $a,b,c>0$ and there must exist a triangle with side lengths $a,b,c$.  This is not a *for-some* scenario.  We can argue a bit about the syntax, but I think this is what the OP meant.

Comment: The problem was changed! See the first post of the starting-poster.

Comment: Then I was right when I said that $x$ greater than $6$ was necessary but not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

With Cauchy-Schwarz 
$$ab+bc+ca\leq a^2+b^2+c^2$$
then
$$5(a^2+b^2+c^2)< x(ab+bc+ca)\leq x(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$
then $x>5$ is an answer.

Comment: But for $x=5$ we'll get a wrong inequality.

Answer (score 0):

With $M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $v = (a,b,c)$ we have

$$
x v^{\top}M v - 5 v^{\top}I_3 v > 0
$$

or

$$
v^{\top}\left(x M - 5 I_3\right) v > 0
$$

so

$$
x M - 5 I_3 > 0
$$

should be positive definite with eigenvalues

$$
\left\{-\frac{1}{2} (x+10) > 0,-\frac{1}{2} (x+10) > 0,x-5 > 0\right\}
$$

or finally

$$
(x < -10) \cap (x > 5)
$$

which is a contradiction. Considering now that $a > 0, b > 0, c > 0$ we have that $x > 5$ suffices.

Answer (score 0):

HINT AND QUESTION.- Never we have $ab+bc+ca\gt a^2+b^2+c^2$ so never we have
$ab+bc+ca\gt n(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$. It follows, as necessary condition, that the integer $x$ must be greater than $5$.

It remains to discuss the triangular condition. I can not see this clearly.

Look at the minimum value $x=6$. We have with the parameter $a$ that the couples $(b,c)=(x,y)$ that satisfy $$6(ax+ay+xy)\gt 5(a^2+x^2+y^2)$$ are all inside an ellipse. Making $a\ge b\ge c$ these ellipses they grow with $a$ but this $a$ can tend to zero and the corresponding ellipse tends to be a point. [image] Here I do not see clearly the formation of a possible triangle. I leave the question here.